# How to subtract from a specific date and have it land on a weekday while counting weekend days in the subtraction?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So my question is how do I subtract from a specific dates, while counting weekends and having the end result land on a weekday. For example: If I have a dates in `Column F` and I have subtractions/additions in columns `B-E`

`Column B Subtracts 36 Days`

`Column C Subtracts 21 Days`

`Column D Adds 7 Days`

`Column E Subtracts 11 Days`

If in `Column F` for example is `1/26/2020` The Columns according to the equations above would equal:

`B - 12/21/2019`

`C - 1/5/2020`

`D - 2/2/2020`

`E - 1/15/2020`

What I would like the formula to do is, if it lands on a `Saturday` subtract 1 and land on a `Friday` and if it lands on `Sunday` add 1 and land on `Monday` so the result would look like the following:

`B - 12/20/2019`

`C - 1/6/2020`

`D - 2/3/2020`

`E - 1/15/2020`

I have tried doing `WORKDAY` formula but gives me incorrect dates if I keep the equations above. Is there a way to write a formula that would still count `WEEKENDS` (Saturday & Sunday are considered Weekends in this example) and be able to land on `Friday` instead of `Saturday` and land on `Monday` instead of `Sunday`

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To illustrate how to work the formula, I set up the test data in a manner similar to your description.

[image]

The formulas in row 2 are simply:

```
          Column B        Column C        Column D        Column E
Row 2:    =$F$2+B1        =$F$2+C1        =$F$2+D1        =$F$2+E1
Row 3:    =WEEKDAY(B2,1)  =WEEKDAY(C2,1)  =WEEKDAY(D2,1)  =WEEKDAY(E2,1)
```

In order to make the difference calculation avoid the weekend, you'll have to use an `IF` statement. So in my example data, cell B5 holds the formula:

```
=IF(WEEKDAY($F$2+B$1)=7,($F$2+B$1)-1,IF(WEEKDAY($F$2+B$1)=1,($F$2+B$1)+1,($F$2+B$1)))
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you so much, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

A little bit simpler formula:

```
=((A1+A2)-(WEEKDAY(A1+A2,1)=7)+(WEEKDAY(A1+A2,1)=1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
B2: =$F2+B$1+CHOOSE(WEEKDAY($F2+B$1,16),-1,1,0,0,0,0,0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In `B2`, a shorter formula copied across right :

```
=B$1+$F2+TEXT(MOD(B$1+$F2,7)-1,"\0;-1;1")
```

[image]